# Inconsistent tooltip for the 'Stack Exchange' button in the topbar

Tags: bug, top-bar, stackexchange.com, tooltips

Hovering over the 'StackExchange' button on the topbar in Meta, the tooltip currently says:

> [image]
>
> A list of all 150 Stack Exchange sites

However, on http://stackexchange.com, it says:

> [image]
>
> A list of all 151 Stack Exchange sites

1. What is the extra site? (Note: the reason can't be: 'because you're on that 1 extra site' because it says *all* -- so it should include the current one!)
2. Please can it be made consistent with all sites?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems this isn't a bug with the counting of sites at all (my previous answer was wrong). The problem is in the sync of the API that powers the StackExchange.com site.

As Adam Lear commented:

> Eh, the two are supposed to be in sync, but there's some weirdness there with caching and API use. Probably too minor to really worry about until we have time to rip out API calls out of stackexchange.com since it doesn't really need to go about getting that data in a roundabout way anymore.

Comment: Agreed -- this would make it more consistent and less confusing! :)

Comment: I am wondering: Why is there a number anyway? What does it matter?

Comment: good question...! It might be to 'wow' new users when they hover over it and they see a big number: they'd be like 'wooooooowwwww that's a lot of sites' :P

Comment: I think it should be 150 on all sites. I've done a quick check on that drop-down on both meta.se and stackexchange, and there seems to be 150 sites listed on each.

Comment: Eh, the two are supposed to be in sync, but there's some weirdness there with caching and API use. Probably too minor to really worry about until we have time to rip out API calls out of stackexchange.com since it doesn't really *need* to go about getting that data in a roundabout way anymore.

Comment: @AnnaLear Why not post that as an 'official' answer? :)

Comment: Indeed. Since I am wrong I would delete my answer, but the comment is useful.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ moved the comment into my answer so it is clear why this happens. Hope it gets fixed any time.